# Adding external Libraries in my CmakeList

Tags: c++, cmake, qmake

I need your help to add a windows 10 libraries located in -"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.17763.0/um/x64 to my Cmakelist. I need these libraries to build my program, I have done with QMake (see image ) [image] but I'm now trying to do it in CMakeList

The libraries are -lshell32 -luser32 -ldxguid -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -ldinput8

Thanks,

Comment: Try to open `Start` on Windows and type in `Developer Command Prompt`, this is a console in which there are set up appropriate environment variables for Windows libraries, try launching compilation from here

Comment: The command to add external libraries in `CMake` is  target_link_libraries(). The documentation is here: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/command/target_link_libraries.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/command/target_link_libraries.html)

Comment: You may want to start with this tutorial if you don't have CMake experience: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: i added  this Line :    
target_link_libraries(hello -lshell32 -luser32 -ldxguid -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -ldinput8) , hello is my .exe, but its seems like it does not work